# NSURLConnection hits didFailWithError when the URL actually exists

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send a simple NSURLConnection request:

```
- (void) sendHTTPRequest:(NSString*)urlString
{
NSLog(@"SendHTTPRequest: %@", urlString);

@try
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];

    // Create the request.        
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else {
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    }
}
@catch (NSException *e)
{
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
}
```

It calls back to:
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

with an error of: Connection failed! Error - The requested URL was not found on this server.

However, this url does work.  I can access it with my browser with no issues.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `fileURLWithPath:path` is only used for valid **system** paths. For "Internet"-URLs, you are supposed to use `[NSURL urlWithString:urlString];`